# Trying to rotate a button in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to rotate a button in jquery!

This is what I've created on jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/QVKjt/1/

jquery code

```
$("#no").rotate({ 
    angle:0,
        bind: {
            click : function(){
                var curAngle = parseInt($(this).getRotateAngle());
                $(this).rotate({
                    angle: curAngle,
                    animateTo: curAngle + 30
                });
            }
        }
   });
```

Comment: load the required rotate.js file in the fiddle... it is not working beacuse rotate.js is not loaded..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.rotate()` isn't an official jQuery function and you need to load it manually.

To do this, [download the library by clicking here](https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/downloads/detail?name=jQueryRotate.2.2.js) and refer to your application using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQueryRotate.2.2.js"></script>
```

In jsFiddle I just add an external library. To see working, [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/QVKjt/3/).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var rotation = 0;

jQuery.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
    $(this).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
};

$('#no').click(function() {
    rotation += 30;
    $(this).rotate(rotation);
});
```

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chiragvidani/QVKjt/9/) demo

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is help you.

```
$("#no").rotate({ 
angle:0,
    bind: {
        click : function(){
            $(this).rotate({
                angle: 0,
                animateTo:  30
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Check the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/QVKjt/8/